# Vue Router - Same path, but different components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

If the components for path "**/users**" and "**/users/user-reference**" are completely different and unrelated, how should I make a structure in the router configuration when using Vue 3 Composition API?

optionA:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/users', component: Users },
  { path: '/users/user-reference', component: UserReference },
];
```

OptionB:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/users',
    component: Users,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user-reference',
        component: UserReference
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

With the OptionB the child component should be inside the parent path's component with `<router-view/>`.

So the OptionB is wrong.

What you want is a default child component:

```
import {RouterView} from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/users',
    component: RouterView,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: User
      },
      {
        path: 'user-reference',
        component: UserReference
      }
    ]
  }
];
```